# VSCode (C++) - see what symbols are used from includes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm looking for a way (maybe an extension) to see what symbols are used with a given include statement. It would be really useful, especially to see which includes are actually useless.

I tried `include-what-you-use` but it's not exactly what I want and it doesn't integrate with VS Code (extension seems to be broken).

Any ideas ?

Exemple:

```
// a.h

class A {};
class B {};

// c.h
#include a.h    // some popup or smth to say only `A` is used

class C : public A {};
```

Comment: comment out all your includes, and uncomment some until there are no errors

Comment: haha it doesn't sound like the most practical solution :/

Comment: why not, most of the includes you know you need, just a single one might be needed before, just comment and see if you get errors

Comment: I have hundreds of files, with usually at least ten includes per file. I'm looking for something I can integrate with my coding workflow (like a hover popup).